# Cannot get post thumbnails to display

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm stumped. I've pored over all the articles here and beyond to no avail. I'm trying to simply display the post thumbnail in a template page, but it will not show up.

I have thumbnails enabled for the theme in functions.php: `add_theme_support ('post-thumbnails');`

I removed the sizing function `set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );` from functions.php and added `array(150,150)` as an argument to `get_the_post_thumbnail`

I've set the Featured Image in a couple posts to test it out.

I tried echoing out `get_the_post_thumbnail` and using `the_post_thumbnail` template tag. I tried both `get_posts` (along with `setup_postdata($post);`) and `new WP_query` methods. No such luck.

I don't think it matters, but I'm using a child of the Twenty Eleven theme.

I have a template page set up and I'm calling a function I created in functions.php to list the posts. I'd like to use get_posts and echo it out like this: `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(150,150) )`. I've also tried inserting the function straight into the template page.

I've made every tweak I could think of. I don't see anything I'm overlooking, seems pretty straight forward. Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I had initially before trying all the tweaks mentioned above.

**In the functions.php file:**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}

set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
```

**And in my page template file:**

```
function list_posts_by_cat_auth_year ($cat_text, $cat_id, $author, $year) {

echo '
<h1>'.$cat_text.'</h1>
<br />
<ol>';
global $post;

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'numberposts' => 0, 'category' => $cat_id, 'author' => $author, 'order' => 'desc' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        echo '
        <li>
        <div style="float:left">'
        .get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(150,150) ).'
        </div>
        <a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
        <br />
        <span class="post-summary">Posted on '.get_the_time('D, M jS, Y').' by '.$author->first_name.
        '<br />'.
        get_the_tag_list('Tagged:  ',' , ','').'
        </span>
        <br />
        ';

        echo '
        </li>
        <br />';
    };
echo '
</ol>
';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked (meaning, it may have been updated in 3.5 and I just haven't noticed), passing an array for an arbitrary image size hasn't worked since before WordPress 3.0. You have to pass a pre-defined image size. Try:

1. Define your custom image size:

   ```
   add_image_size( 'some-custom-name', 150, 150, true );
   ```

   (called along with `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`)
2. Then **regenerate your thumbnails** (e.g. via Plugin)
3. Then pass your custom image size as the `$size` parameter:

   ```
   get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'some-custom-name' )
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and still no thumbnails. Any other ideas?

Comment: You're welcome. :) But did it work?

Comment: Negative. Accidentally hit enter before.

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'some-custom-name' ) )` return?

Comment: it returns `string(0) ""` I'm assuming that means it's not finding a thumbnail. on the edit post screen I definitely have the Featured Image set.

Comment: Okay, and what does `var_dump( $post )` return?

Comment: it returns all post object array items. the code is too long to post here apparently, so here's a pastebin link: [link](http://pastebin.com/w5JvN9Q7)

Comment: i should mention it also returned all of the post content in the middle of that post object array

Comment: And one more: what does `var_dump( get_post_meta( $post->ID ) )` return?

Comment: it returns: `array(4) { ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1355253532:1" } ["image"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "937" } ["_image"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "field_506d979d5c193" } }`

Comment: The lack of a `'_thumbnail_id'` post meta key indicates that WordPress doesn't think the post has a featured image defined.

Comment: Final one to check, just to be sure: `var_dump( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )`

Comment: Now it just returns error (unexpected ';') because I don't think it's returning anything there. So how is that possible? The Featured Image is set and comes up on Edit Post screen. How can I remedy that?

Comment: Alright, I finally got it. Even though I was choosing Featured Image from the metabox, for some reason it wasn't updating correctly. I had to click Upload Media and from that screen I set the Featured Image and now it's working. Yeesh.

Comment: perhaps once fixed `add_image_size( 'some-custom-name', 150, 150, true );`you need something like this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/acme-fix-images/ to generate missing thumbnails

Comment: yes, it won't resize images you have already uploaded, when you add a new image size. Run https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ after adding a new thumbnail size, to update existing images.